# postgres: unable to drop table in schema, error mentions unrelated schema

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

I have a number of schemas set up:

**schemas:**

```
hg=# \dn
 _timescaledb_cache    | postgres
 _timescaledb_catalog  | postgres
 _timescaledb_internal | postgres
 hg_quotes_raw         | zoolander
 hg_trade_volume_1m    | zoolander
 hg_trade_volume_day   | zoolander
 hg_trades_raw         | zoolander
 public                | postgres
```

Within each of the `hg_xxx` schemas I have a number of tables (most with common table names):

**hg_quotes_raw:**

```
hg=# \dt hg_quotes_raw.*
 hg_quotes_raw | hgf7 | table | zoolander
 hg_quotes_raw | hgf8 | table | zoolander
 ...
 hg_quotes_raw | hgz6 | table | zoolander
 hg_quotes_raw | hgz7 | table | zoolander
```

**hg_trade_volume_1m:**

```
hg=# \dt hg_trade_volume_1m.*
 hg_trade_volume_1m | hgf7 | table | zoolander
 hg_trade_volume_1m | hgf8 | table | zoolander
 ...
 hg_trade_volume_1m | hgz6 | table | zoolander
 hg_trade_volume_1m | hgz7 | table | zoolander
```

I have one such table, `hg_trade_volume_1m.hgq8`, as detailed below:

```
hg=# \d hg_trade_volume_1m.hgq8
 time   | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | 
 volume | integer                  |           |          | 

hg=# select * from hg_trade_volume_1m.hgq8 limit 5;
 2016-12-16 09:32:00-05 |     88
 2016-12-16 13:45:00-05 |     88
 2016-12-22 13:42:00-05 |     86
 2017-01-04 11:43:00-05 |     43
 2017-01-04 13:38:00-05 |     22
```

### Problem:

When I attempt to **drop** this table, I get an error saying a **different schema** doesn't exist:

```
hg=# drop table if exists hg_trade_volume_1m.hgq8;
ERROR:  schema "hg_raw_quotes" does not exist
```

My table persists after this drop statement:

```
hg=# \d hg_trade_volume_1m.hgq8
 time   | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | 
 volume | integer                  |           |          | 

hg=# select * from hg_trade_volume_1m.hgq8 limit 5;
 2016-12-16 09:32:00-05 |     88
 2016-12-16 13:45:00-05 |     88
 2016-12-22 13:42:00-05 |     86
 2017-01-04 11:43:00-05 |     43
 2017-01-04 13:38:00-05 |     22
```

### Questions:

- Why can I not drop this table?
- Why does postgres mention a different schema in the error message?

### Notes:

The schema mentioned in the error message used to exist, but has since been removed from the database.

```
hg=# \dn hg_raw_quotes
```

Please also note that the table (and related timescaledb hypertable) was not originally created in the schema, but rather migrated to the schema after creation. Not sure if this could be an underlying cause?

Comment: "The schema mentioned in the error message does actually exist": Maybe, but it's not the one you presented here: "hg_raw_quotes" (in the error message) vs "hg_quotes_raw" (what you showed here) (note the different positions of "raw" and "quotes").

Comment: Does `drop table if exists hg_trade_volume_1m.hgq8 CASCADE;` work?

Comment: @stickybit ah, well caught! D'oh! So that schema *used* to exist, but no longer... I'll update the question. Thanks!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no it doesn't - I did try that.

Comment: Seems this might be a bug with timescaledb